# vc++ 6.0 crashing on server 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Every time I open a project workspace vc++ crashes with an exception code of c000005.

I've done numerous installs of visual studio 6 on win7 and do not seem to have this issue there. This is the first time i've tried on Server2008R2.

Installation was done with UAC off. VC++ is set to run as admin with compatibility of XP SP3.

I patched up through SP6 for visual studio 6. The problem remains after the patch.

Additionally, I set the \Users group to have full control since I discovered that c000005 was a memory violation and I thought the issue may be security access related. No changes.

What is going on here?

Comment: The C/C++ component of Visual Studio 6 is not supported on anything later than XP. Contrary to what you say, it will not install properly on Win 7. Microsoft have hard coded the installation failure into the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up taking my solution to a xp virtual machine and converting the project up to 2003, then to 2010.

I then went to my production server and installed vc++ 2010 express and brought over my upgraded solution and now all is well.

It's still odd that vb6 ide works fine on win7/server08r2 but vc++6 does not. Possibly again if I face the same issue and can afford to spend time digging into it I may find the actual fix to make the IDE work on the new server OS.